# SQL Server: how to get average date

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get average date  for my table result (result.regDate as datetime). I found on another topic following code:

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(regDate AS INT)) AS DATETIME) FROM result;
```

But i'm getting following error:

> The explicit conversion of the date data type to float is not permitted.

Am i doing something false or is this statement false?

Comment: Why are you casting a date as an INT?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about [Arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average), which `AVG` calculates: An average over dates doesn't make mathematical sense. Sure, you can fool `sql server` to spit out a value, but I wouldn't bet my life on the meaning of that date.

Comment: @HoneyBadger why not? The date should be a unique value.

Comment: @JacobH, uniqueness has nothing to do with it (and I don't see where it says the date is unique). Arithmetic mean is `(X1 + Xn)/n`. What is January 1st 2016 + May 15th 2016?

Comment: When I query that in SSMS I get March 9th. That's correct right? Try it yourself.

Comment: The integer value for Jan 01 2016 is 42368, for May 16 2016 it is 42504. The average is 42436 aka March 9.

Comment: @HoneyBadger here you go: CREATE TABLE DateTest 
(Datetest  datetime)

INSERT INTO DateTest
VALUES ('2016-05-16')
INSERT INTO DateTest
VALUES ('2016-01-01')

SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(Datetest AS FLOAT)) AS datetime) FROM DateTest

Comment: @HoneyBadger my point about uniqueness was that a date represents a literal unique integer value in the database, so therefore averaging the integer will produce the correct date result.

Comment: @JacobH, you're probably right. My gut still says you can't add dates, but if you see them as days since 1 (as SQL server does internally), then why not...

Comment: I found this code on another topic, I don't know, why they used this.My column's typ is date, not datetime

Answer (score 1):

The following code returns the average - but only as year:

```
SELECT AVG(YEAR(regDate)) FROM results
```

This helped me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using another Date-Time datatype (i.e. `Date` or `DateTime2` or `SmallDateTime`), then you need to cast it as `DateTime` BEFORE casting it as a `Float` - *then* cast it back to `DateTime` (after calling AVG) *before* implicitly using against (or explicitly casting as) another Date-Time datatype.

Here's the "*fool-proof*" SQL:

```
CAST( AVG(CAST(CAST(regDate as DateTime) as Float)) as DateTime)
```

Caveat: If you are using Dates that fall out of the normal range of dates the `DateTime` datatype supports (i.e. anytime before the year `1753`), then you will need to consider a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast it to `float` not `int`, Try:

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(regDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) FROM result
```

Comment: the same error:
> The explicit conversion of the date data type to float is not permitted.